# Could you give some advise about linear algebra "The proof for the nonhomogeneous equation $Ax=b$, with $b\neq0$"

Tags: linear-algebra

**Theorem:** If $\,A\,$ is a $\,m\times n\,$ matrix, then the linear system $\,Ax=B\,$ has no solutions, one solution, or infinitely many solution.

---

I can't understand about this Theorem's proof.
Could you help some advise?

This Threorem's proof giving like that...

> if $x$ and $y$ are distinct solutions to the homogeneous system $Ax = 0$,
> then $x + cy$ is a solution for every real number $c$.

so

> $A(x + cy) = A (x) + A(cy) = Ax + cAy = 0 + c0 = 0 $

hence, $\,x + cy\,$ is a solution to the homogeneous system.

The same result holds for the nonhomogeneous equation $\,Ax = b\,,\;$ with $\,b\neq0\,.$

Let $u$ and $v$ be distinct solutions to $Ax=b$, and $c$ a real number. Then

> $$A(v+c(u-v)) = Av + A(c(u-v)) = Av + cAu - cAv = b + cb - cb = b$$

But, I can't understand why we let
$$v+c(u-v)$$
when it changes from $Ax = 0$ to $Ax = b$.

I think **v** and **u** are the giving distinct solutions, so write as upper proof form like...
$$A(u+cv)$$not$$A(v+c(u-v))$$

Could you give me some advice? Thank you.

Comment: Their sentence "The *same* result holds for the nonhomogeneous equation $Ax = b$ with $b\ne0$" is inexact. If $u,v$ are solutions of $Ax=b,$ what is true (and they prove it) is that $u+c(u-v)$ also  is a solution. Whereas $A(u+cv)=(1+c)b\ne b$ (if $b,c\ne0$).

Comment: @AnneBauval I really Thanks for your help, but I'm still confused. 

1. I think "distinct solutions" means not the same solutions like $u≠v$, not $u=v$. Is this correct?
`\n`
2.  You mean "The same result holds for the nonhomogeneous equation $Ax=b$
 with $b≠0$" is not correct sentence? This sentence came the book [Introduction to Linear Algebra with Applications,  James DeFranza, 2015] page 50 and 51, Example 3 & Theorem 11. 
`\n`
3. I'm really sorry, because I can't understand your comment. Can I understand like this video, [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjsPjh0B2tU)?

Comment: This video is interesting but your problem is much more elementary. In my comment I am not saying that your book is wrong but that the formulation "the same result holds" is misleading. It is not exactly "the same". It is what they wrote (and proved) about $u,v.$ Don't pay attention to the word "distinct". Everything holds as well when $u=v$ (but the result in that case is less interesting ;-) ).

Comment: "But, I can't understand why we let...": what cann't you understand? 1) why what they wrote is true? or 2) how it helps to solve the exercise?

If it is 2), here is my answer: What we must prove is that $Ax=b$ has at least 2 distinct solutions, then it has infinitely many. So, assume we have 2 solutions $u\ne v.$ Then, by their lemma, for every $c\in\Bbb R,$ $u_c:=v+c(u-v)$ is also a solution. But these $u_c$ are distinct for distinct values of $c$ (because $u-v\ne0$), hence $\{u_c\mid c\in\Bbb R\}$ is infinite, hence so is the supset of all solutions.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you so much to help understanding. I'm too late, because I need more time to find more informations about solving this question. Now, I understand because of your help :)